# Insert adwords tracker using php include and jQuery load method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-ads-api, tracker

Lately I received a project made from another programmer but is giving me some issues, the app is like a wizard form, and inside of this php page there is a include page is like a warning or something, in this warning included the div wrapper is hidden, and only shows depending of a logic that is being run. So basically the client needs a tracker for this warning, so he insert it inside of the warning include page. But has you imagine this is giving issues since the tracker fires up always even when is hidden.

So what I did is inside the include warning I put this div:

```
<div id="adwords-not">
</div>
```

And then when the div warning is displayed and inject this code:

```
$( "#adwords-not" ).load( "adwords-tracker.html" );
```

Inside the adwords-tracker.html I inserted the goodle adwords tracker code. But i notice that now the tracker doesn't work, is not being fire or is like that doesn't exist. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Adwords conversion code after the page as loaded as it uses `document.write`. The best alternative is to use the asynchronous version of the conversion tracker.

See [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/asynchronous/) for the documentation (note that even though the article is about remarketing tags, it works exactly the same for conversion tags.)